# usage of django context variable as html tag attribute

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I'm trying to understand how context variables work in templates.

Is it mandatory to use quotations around the context variable.
for example if my code is as follows

```
view:

def view(req):
    return render(req, 'index.html', {'class': 'style'}


html:

<h1 class="{{class}}">hello world</h1>
```

i saw the above usage in several places.

here my doubt is since it's a string variable, can it be used without quotations like?

```
<h1 class={{class}}>Hello World</h1>
```

Or is there any reason to use those quotations?
because those two are working same.
am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

In the example `{'class': 'style'}`, 'class' is not really a string variable, per se, it's really the Name of a Name/Value pair, which is an element of a dictionary type object in python. In dictionaries, the Name is also referred to as the 'key'

The key doesn't have to be a string.  In python it can be any immutable type (including numbers and tuples... if the tuple contains only string and numbers and tuples etc). The value could be almost anything, even another dictionary!

In the example `<h1 class="{{class}}">hello world</h1>` the quotes are there because HTML requires quotes for setting the class attribute. When the Value 'style' is defined, the quotes indicate that the value *is* a string, but they are not part *of* the string that gets returned, so they need to be included explicitly in the template.

On the other hand if you set {'class': '"style"'}, the inner quotes would be included in the string and you could use `<h1 class={{class}}>hello world</h1>`